# SQL grouping issue cause duplicate rows instead of grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Somehow my SQL does not group properly. I want to have just one line per invoice. I do not want the column categoryid but I think that caused the query to output two lines (or more) per invoice.

```
select invoices.InvoiceID, 
    InvoiceDate,
    month(InvoiceDate) as 'month',
    year(InvoiceDate) as 'year',
    CustomerCompanyName,
    countryname,
    case when CATEGORIES.ParentCategoryID in (125,183) and CATEGORIES.CategoryID not in (162, 163, 164, 165) then
        count(SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.ProductID) 
    else
        0
    end as Qnt
--  ,CATEGORIES.CategoryID -- this line showed me that it does not group by categoryid somehow...
from INVOICES
inner join CUSTOMERS on invoices.CustomerID = customers.CustomerID
inner join COUNTRIES on CUSTOMERS.CountryID = COUNTRIES.CountryID
inner join shipments on shipments.invoiceid = invoices.invoiceid and shipments.ShipmentCancelled = 0
inner join SHIPMENTPRODUCTS on shipments.shipmentid = SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.ShipmentID
inner join products on SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.ProductID = products.productid
inner join CATEGORIES on products.CategoryID = CATEGORIES.CategoryID
group by invoices.InvoiceID, 
    invoices.InvoiceDate, 
    customers.customercompanyname, 
    countries.CountryName, 
    CATEGORIES.ParentCategoryID, 
    CATEGORIES.CategoryID
```

[image]

I know I can fix this by inserting the results in a temptable and grouping that. or by using a sub-select. But I'd like to just have this fixed without a subselect or temp table. It must be a small error in my grouping or joins but I do not see it.

Comment: i think the company names are different on the 2 rows. try removing it from the select and group by

Comment: Maybe its because your `GroupBy ` statement contains `CategoryId` and they are not the same

Comment: it needs to be in the group by smss says. because I need it in the case statement.

Comment: @JPHellemons Than wrap your statement into another statement which selects all data from the result and finally group it without the CategoryId

Comment: @viper you mean instead of the case a sub query? is there no other (fast) option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want conditional aggregation:

```
select invoices.InvoiceID, InvoiceDate,
       month(InvoiceDate) as [month], year(InvoiceDate) as [year],
       CustomerCompanyName, countryname,
       sum(case when CATEGORIES.ParentCategoryID in (125,183) and CATEGORIES.CategoryID not in (162, 163, 164, 165)
                then 1 else 0
           end) as Qnt
```

Then leave `CategoryId` and `ParentCategoryId` out of the `group by` clause.

Comment: spot on! Thanks a conditional aggregation is exactly what I was looking for. SMSS told me that I needed the fields in the group by. which did not seem logical.

Comment: my second field which I left out the question looks similar to the case one you fixed. only then instead of a count(tableid) it has this subquery `(select count(SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.ProductID) * sum(ORDERSPRODUCTS.SoldFor) from ordersproducts where ordersproducts.orderid = SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.orderid
 -- and SHIPMENTPRODUCTS.productid = ORDERSPRODUCTS.productid)` can I convert that in an conditional aggregation too?

Comment: Never mind, found it: sum(case when CATEGORIES.ParentCategoryID in (125,183) and CATEGORIES.CategoryID not in (162, 163, 164, 165) then
  ORDERSPRODUCTS.SoldFor
 else
  0
 end) as Bruto 
and some more inner joins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `CategoryId` from `select` as well as `group by`

Comment: it was already commented out and smss says it is required in the group by because it is in the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

As an example to the comment i posted before where i suggested to wrap the statement with another statement and let the column `CategoryId` away:

```
select T.InvoiceId,
       T.InvoiceDate,
       T.Month,
       T.Year,
       T.CustomerCompanyName,
       T.countryname,
       Sum( T.Qnt ) as QNT    // not sure about this at the moment

  from (

     // TODO: insert your query

  ) T

group by T.InvoiceID, 
         T.InvoiceDate,
         T.month,
         T.year,
         T.CustomerCompanyName,
         T.countryname,
         T.Qnt
```